# how to not focus on the search bar when the shortcut key is pressed in the textarea in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a search bar and I added a shortcut to it.

## Searchbox.js

```js
const ShortcutKey = (key, callback)=> {
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback)
  useEffect(() => {callbackRef.current = callback})

  useEffect(() => {
    function handle(event){
      if (event.code === key) callbackRef.current(event)
    }
      document.addEventListener('keyup', handle)
      return () => document.addEventListener('keyup', handle)
  }, [key])
}
```

the above code focuses on the search bar when '/' is pressed

but I also have a textarea in my other component

## post.js

```js
          <form className="form" onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
            <TextArea
              style={{ minHeight: '10rem' }}
              name="create-post"
              placeholder="Share your brilliant thought!"
              onChange={handleMessageChange}
              value={message}
              label="Create Post"
              hideLabel={true}
              error={error}
            />
            <Button type="submit" size="md" color="main" text="Mumble Now" iconName="comment-alt" />
          </form>
```

I don't want to focus on the search bar when a user presses '/' in the textarea.

**Please help on how to not focus on the searchbar when '/' is pressed in the textarea**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check inside the `callback`, you pass to the `ShortcutKey`, if the event originated in an `input`/`textarea` element and not perform the action in that case

Something like

```
<ShortcutKey key="Slash" callback={(event)=>{
  // if event occured in an input or textarea do nothing
  if (event.target.closest('input, textarea')) return;
  
  // focus on the searchbox
  // ...
}} />
```